# If count(column) Then Select in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

can I do something like this in oracle?
I want to check if the result dataset is more than 20k records then DO NOT SELECT, if less than 20k then SELECT.

```
DECLARE cnt number;
BEGIN
select count(*) into cnt from ir_mpn where material LIKE '%A00%';
IF cnt > 20000 THEN
   select manuf_part, material, vendor, vendor_name from ir_mpn where material LIKE '%A00%';
END IF;
END;
```

I tried to do like this but shows error:

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 4:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Any better suggestions for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is PL/SQL so your `SELECT` statement requires an `INTO` clause. As you're about to return thousands of rows, you can't return them into scalar variables but e.g. collection or ref cursor.

However, if you want to do it in SQL, then see if this helps; example is based on Scott's `DEPT` table:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON
```

I'd want to select rows from it if number of rows is less than 3; as number of rows is 4, nothing is returned:

```
SQL> select * from dept
  2  where 3 >= (select count(*) from dept);

no rows selected
```

How about 5 rows?

```
SQL> select * from dept
  2  where 5 >= (select count(*) from dept);

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

In your case:

```
select manuf_part, material, vendor, vendor_name 
from ir_mpn 
where material LIKE '%A00%'
  and 20000 >= (select count(*) 
                from ir_mpn
                where material like '%A00%'
               );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But this only works for simple straight forward query. If for long query with joins, it take time.

Comment: Of course it does. There ain't no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: Or in other words, can I terminate the query in Oracle when the query had read and processed 20k of records? <--- I was asked this.... As I have to use "like" in the query, sometimes it can select up to 2 millions records. Therefore, I was actually requested to terminate the query when it reach processed 20k of records. They don't want to let it process all and take long time...Any idea??

Comment: The simplest option is to `select ... from ir_mpn where ... and rownum <= 20000`; the last condition will make sure that query returns at most 20.000 rows

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to return nothing if there are less than 20,001 matching rows, and also limit the results to 20K in total? So if there are 15K rows, show nothing, and if there are 25K rows, show 20K?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Good morning sir, I want to return nothing when reach 20,001 records.

Comment: @Littlefoot But I'm not allowed to use rownum as my boss said that rownum actually process everything of the 2 millions records then only shows the 20k. This is why I'm confusing.

Comment: If there's no aggregation or ORDER BY or DISTINCT, then pure SELECT will return "randomly" picked rows from the table and stop once it reaches the limit. You should perform some tests, using options suggested in this discussion. Don't run them only once, but several times (to avoid possible caching issues), and then see which one behaves the best.

Comment: @YiHarn So if there are 15K rows, show nothing, and if there are 25K rows, show 20K?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson When more than 20K records, show nothing. Below 20k, show them.

Comment: @Littlefoot Noted, thank you so much! I had suggested to my boss ytd morning to use rownum and the way you had suggested ytd. Both not accepted. Still researching and struggling. By the way thank you so much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Depends on what do you like to achieve.

In PL/SQL you cannot use plain `SELECT` to return rows.
Some options are to use `INTO` (like you did for `COUNT()`) or use cursor (like below).

The simple approach is:

```
for r_material in (select manuf_part, material, vendor, vendor_name from ir_mpn where material LIKE '%A00%') loop
 -- process each r_material record here f.e.
 -- if r_material.vendor = 'ORACLE' then...
end loop;
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much!